# Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Migration Issue

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2010

I pray this reaches you in the best of health & highest of spirits today. I am having an issue with an Exchange 2010 mailbox migration. There are two Exchange servers I am working on as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I have begun setting up new e-mail users on the new server **(EXCHANGESVR)** as indicated in the next screenshot:

[image]

Now, the quagmire I am having is that none of the users that were created on the old server **(MULUMBASVR)** are unable to be migrated to the new server. Below is such a user:

[image]

For the gurus in Exchange, is it possible to recreate the old mailboxes on the new server that's been set up? *(Another error I am receiving is that the old mailbox database is inaccessible. It's as if it has been deleted.)*

I am at my wit's end & willing to accept any help on this issue.

Warm regards,

Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what happens when you try to move a mailbox - therefore not enough information to go on.

The most common reason for move mailboxes failing is lack of Permission Inheritance enabled on the user account. You need to enable that in ADUC on the security tab.